# Does taking quotients preserve isomorphism of rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $A$ and $B$ be subrings of $R$. Suppose also that an ideal $I$ of $R$ is contained in both $A$ and $B$ (so $I$ is an ideal of both $A$ and $B$).

I have two questions:

1. If $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic (as rings), does this mean $A/I$ and $B/I$ are isomorphic?
2. If $A/I$ and $B/I$ are isomorphic, does this mean $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic?

I have thought about this for a few days and I think both should be false, but I haven't been able to construct any counterexamples to these. This isn't part of the course I'm doing now, but I thought these questions are rather interesting.

Note: I consider all rings (and subrings) to be unital. Also, an isomorphism of rings should send $1$ to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers are no.

For (1) consider the ring $R = k[x, y] \oplus k[x, y]$ where $k$ is any field you like.  Take the subrings $A = k[x^2, x^3, y] \oplus k[x, y]$ (so in the left factor monomials can't have $x$-degree $1$) and $B = k[x, y] \oplus k[x^2, x^3, y]$.  These are clearly isomorphic.  Let $I = (x^2, x^3) \oplus (0)$.  Then $A/I \simeq k[y] \oplus k[x, y]$ and $B/I \simeq k[x, y]/x^2 \oplus k[x^2, x^3, y]$.  You might just believe by inspection that these are non-isomorphic.  One way to see it rigorously is to note that there are no nonzero elements in $A/I$ that square to zero.

For (2) consider the ring $R = k[x] \oplus k[x, y]/(x^2, xy)$.  Let $A = k[x] \oplus k[y]$ and $B = k[x^2, x^3] \oplus k[x,y]/(x^2, xy)$.  Looking at square zero elements one sees these are nonisomorphic.  Both contain the ideal $I = (x^2, x^3) \oplus (y)$ and their quotients by this ideal are $A/I \simeq k[x]/x^2 \oplus k$ and $B/I \simeq k \oplus k[x]/x^2$ and these are clearly isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks! If possible, may I know how you arrived at these rings? I've been thinking about this for days and couldn't come up with any.. Also, do you happen to know other "simpler" examples which don't involve polynomial rings in two variables? I ask this because I have just started my course in abstract algebra and am still not too familiar with many rings (though if I extrapolate correctly, I think I know what your rings mean). The rings I have currently been introduced to are polynomial rings in one variable, the integers, rationals, etc..

Comment: I don't know of simpler examples, I came up with these on the spot so there certainly could be better examples out there.  As for how I arrived at them, I was just playing around with the fact that different quotients of different rings can turn out isomorphic.  I put my two different rings in the different factors of the direct sum and then tried to play with things till it all worked.  It was actually harder to get it to work out then I expected.